# File operation to copy one .mp3 file to create another same file

Tags: c, file-io

I was trying to copy the contents of one music file(.mp3) to create another music(.mp3) file. I tried this,

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     #include<conio.h>
     int main()
     {
      FILE *a, *b;
      char c;

     a = fopen("linkinpark.mp3","rb");
     b = fopen("linkinpark1.mp3","wb");
     while((ch = getc(a)) != EOF)
     fprintf(b,"%c",ch);
     fclose(a);
     fclose(b);
     return 0;
     }
```

May be i am making some mistake like using a char variable and writing it in a binary file and also linkinpark1.mp3 is created but its corrupted.
What could be its possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getc()` returns either an `int`, not a `char`.  It needs to return `int` because it returns either the next byte read from the stream as a value between 0 and 255, *or* the value `EOF`, which is typically -1.  Since there are 257 possible outputs, you need to be able to distinguish between the byte 255 and the sentinel `EOF`, but your code is conflating the two.  Hence, once you hit the first byte with value 255, it erroneously cuts the file off short.

If you change `c` to be `int` instead of `char`, it should work correctly.

Comment: i studied a more and looked up to your answer getc(), fgetc() and getchar() all returns unsigned int (not int). So this will also work like unsigned int char;    while((ch=getc(a)) != (unsigned)EOF).

Comment: @mrigendra: No, `getc()`, `fgetc()`, and `getchar()` all return plain `int`, not `unsigned int`.

Comment: in tuboc c index it says "getc returns the character read by converting it to an int without sign extension .

Comment: @mrigendra: Yes, it returns it as an `int`.  It returns a value in the range 0-255, but it's still an `int`.